# How to enable account selection while using google auth in nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am using following code for my Google auth setup in Nuxt in `nuxt.config.js`

```
google: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    codeChallengeMethod: '',
    responseType: 'code',
    endpoints: {
      token: process.env.APP_BASE_URL + '/auth/user/google',
      userInfo: process.env.APP_BASE_URL + '/auth/user/info'
}
```

And `this.$auth.loginWith('google')` when 'login' button is pressed.

Google auth works, but if I am logged in some Google account in my browser, it is automatically selected during my nuxt auth. If not, account selection works fine.

How can I enable account selection in all cases?

Comment: First off, you probably need several accounts to try that one. Otherwise, it's probably something to set up on Google's side.

Comment: @kissu when I have several accounts, account selection window appears, but when I am logged in only into single one - nothing

Comment: Which seems legit and normal.